# How to avoid inserting duplicate objects in List?

Tags: java, list, collections, equals, hashcode

I have two employee objects

```
Employee e1 = new Employee("1");  
Employee e2 = new Employee("1");
```

So how to avoid inserting this second object in following `List`

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Can we use `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods to avoid inserting duplicate objects in the list? How?

Comment: Use a set? Or maybe check before action?

Comment: [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't permit duplicates. So, you just need to migrate to `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

Lists have a method to check if an object is in it or not. It internally uses the `equals()` method.

```
if(!list.contains(e2))
{
    list.add(e2);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add e2 in all cases except when you do a `e2=e1` before the if ?

Comment: Depends on the `equals()` method of the `Employee` class. If it is overridden in a way that two employees with the same name/id are equal it works. And based on the question he implies that this would be the case...

Comment: I think he was referring to the inbuilt .equals() method :)

Comment: Possible... that's why I mentioned that it uses the `equals()` method internally. In any case if you want to use the built-in methods of any Collection to prevent duplicates, you need a custom implementation of `equals()`. Applies to `Set` too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to avoid inserting duplicates . But for that you need to override the [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method of your `Employee` class to define what exactly is `e1.equals(e2)`.

Comment: The question is how to insert elements without duplication. You changed the collection itself.

Comment: I was being specific what to be used under what circumstances. If the Collection needs to avoid duplicate elements you **should** use **Set** instead of **List** , you can brush your teeth even with your customized pedicure brush , but you should use toothbrush !!!

Comment: Why use a list in first place when you want to avoid duplicates, choice of set is a correct idea.

Comment: The choice depends how do i want to store and iterate the collection. HashSet ensures there are no duplicates, gives you an O(1) contains() method but doesn't preserve order.
ArrayList doesn't ensure there are no duplicates, contains() is O(n) but you can control the order of the entries.

Comment: [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, e1 and e2 are not really equal in terms of their hashcode. So you cant really equate it using `.equals()` or `==` or `.hashCode().equals()`. You will have to implement your own method to check for equality based on the data contained in these objects. To Java, every object instantiated using new will be a  different object.

Below is excerpt from the Java Api doc for the hashcode method

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> 1. Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>      execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must
>      consistently return the same integer, provided no information used
>      in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need
>      not remain consistent from one execution of an application to
>      another execution of the same application.
> 2. If two objects are equal
>      according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode
>      method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer
>      result.
> 3. It is not required that if two objects are unequal according
>      to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode
>      method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer
>      results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing
>      distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the
>      performance of hashtables.
>
> **As much as is reasonably practical**, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)